# Wordpress get_avatar_url

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my code:

```
<span><img class="super-avatar" src="<?php echo get_avatar_url(the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"></img><?php the_author(); ?></span>
```

The problem I have:

```
<img class="super-avatar" src="1http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g">
```

Why this "number 1" before the url?

Comment: Can you be more specific what your issue is?

Comment: I'm not seeing the output of `1` in front of the URL when I throw your code into a template. Only thing I see wrong is you're closing tag for your image.`</img>` this  not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@user3571412*, if you look your code, you use [`the_author_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta), it was **echo**. You must use [`get_the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/), cause you have echo before.

```
get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )
```

So your code

```
<span><img class="super-avatar" src="<?php echo get_avatar_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"></img><?php the_author(); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are getting a boolean true value in your function output.  Investigate get_avatar_url() or the_author_meta() source code to find out why. Someone may have modified the function or it's a bug.  Whatever it is, it probably was modified.